# images.xcassets "you don't have permission to move file to a trash"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am using xcode 6.3.2 and having problem when I try to move the image from "Unassigned" to "Universal". I gets a massage says that "You don't have permission to move the file to the trash" and images.xcassets folder get shadowed. I've tried to grant read/write permission to all users although I'm using an admin user with full read/write privileges but the problem still exist. I image scale factors is "Single Vector" but basically the issue with all type of scale factors and not limited to "Single Vector" only.

Comment: can you give sudo chmod 777 to the Xcode project folder and try it .

Comment: I've given read/write permission to the project folder and all sub folders through Get info -> Sharing and permissions - I don't know if this is the proper way to give chmod 777 to the project's folder - but still same issue exist

Comment: I've also used chmod 777 /pathname in Terminal application, but nothing changed

Comment: I've upgraded xcode to 6.4 and it got solved